# IOS charts in ScrollView

Tags: swift, charts, ios-charts

I have a series of charts I want to put on a page so I need a scroll view.

I can not figure out how to properly add then as a subclass. Or if this is even the proper method.

I am using Charts. https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

This is the test code.   I am sure I am doing something stupid.

```
import UIKit
import Charts

class ScrollViewController: UIViewController {

    //    @IBOutlet weak var pieChart: PieChartView!

    lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let view = UIScrollView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.contentSize.height = 2000
        return view
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        setupScrollView()


    }

    func setupScrollView(){

        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true

        // add the chart

        let entry1 = PieChartDataEntry(value: 3.4, label: "first")
        let entry2 = PieChartDataEntry(value: 4.1, label: "second")
        let dataSet = PieChartDataSet(values: [entry1, entry2 ], label: "Test chart")

        let chart = UIView()

        chart.frame.size = CGSize(width: 400, height: 300)
        chart.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100)
        chart.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        let viewCustom = PieChartView()
        viewCustom.data = PieChartData(dataSet: dataSet)

        chart.addSubview(viewCustom)

        scrollView.addSubview( chart )

    }

}
```

Using Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ScrollViews can sometimes be a bit tricky. I would refer to this guide if needed: [Apple documentation for setting up UIScrollViews with autlayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithScrollViews.html)

**Quick solution**

- You are not setting constraints for the chart properly in the scrollView. `UIScrollView`s work a bit differently with constraints, and there are some best practices which are often best to stick to (see above link). However a quick fix for you would just be to set `chart.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` then setting correct constraints for the chart in the scrollView.

#### Detailed answer (including best practices for `UIScrollView`)

Based on your example code you need to do the following few things (i've also included some best practices for scrollviews also as stated in the apple documents).

- **Firstly** *(If the charts should be interractable skip to the next "dot" and add the chart to the scrollView directly without a container view)*. Add `UIView` as container view for the scrollView. Constrain this container view leading, trailing, top, bottom to the corresponding anchor of the scrollView. Also if you want to disable scrolling horizontally: set width anchor of the container view equal to the scrollView width anchor. Remember to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`.
- **Secondly:** Set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` for the chart. Then add it to the container or the scroll view. And set its constraints in its superview! (If charts are dynamically sized like labels you only need one x and one y constraint otherwise make sure height and width are calculable from your constraints also.). If you want the chart to be centered horizontally in the scrollView. Set `chart.centerXanchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXanchor).isActive = true` then chart.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo scrollView.widthAnchor, constant: (subtract or add a constant if desired)).isActive = true`. Since setting leading and
- **Lastly** Dont set the contentSize of the scrollview when it is initiated. Override ’viewDidLayoutSubviews()’ of the view controller, call ’super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()’ then set ’scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollView.frame.width, height: 2000)’
  or whatever height you want if it shall not be dynamic.
- **As a side note:** if you want the scrollView to bounce vertically also (for the feel). In the scrollView initialisation block, set: ’scrollView.bounces = true’ and ’scrollView.alwaysBounceVertically = true’. Also i don't see a reason making the scrollView a lazy var? If you load it up every time that `UIViewController` is loaded its more convenient to declare it as a constant.

#### Edit

- Including an example. You might want to change the layout depending on how you want it to look though. (Don't mix auto layout layouts with non auto layout layout in scrollViews. It way easier to use one.) Change your `setupScrollView()` to this.

  ```
  // Change your scrollView declaration to this if you want it to always bounce.
  let scrollView : UIScrollView = {
      let sView = UIScrollView()
      sView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      sView.bounces = true
      sView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
      sView.contentSize.height = 2000 // I would recommend setting `scrollView.contentSize` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` instead. If you are not using the container View approach.
  }()

  let containerView = UIView() // constant for the containerView.

  func setupScrollView(){

      scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
      scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
      scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
      scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true

      // Setting up containerView and disabling horizontal scrolling of the scrollView.

      containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      scrollView.addSubview(containerView)
      containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
      containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
      containerView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
      containerView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
      containerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true

      // add the chart

      let entry1 = PieChartDataEntry(value: 3.4, label: "first")
      let entry2 = PieChartDataEntry(value: 4.1, label: "second")
      let dataSet = PieChartDataSet(values: [entry1, entry2 ], label: "Test chart")

      // Make sure your chart is setup correctly here as `chart`
      let chart = PieChartView()
      chart.data = PieChartData(dataSet: dataSet)
      chart.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

      containerView.addSubview(chart)

      chart.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
      chart.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
      chart.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400).isActive = true
      chart.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
      // Constrain next charts top anchor to the bottom anchor of this chart if you want multiple charts on a vertical axis.

  }
  ```

Does this help you?

Comment: I am seriously lost, my first journey not using auto layout. I had just added a UIView and a sub-view.  The box now shows but not the chart.

Comment: @diogenes Hm i've never used a scrollView without auto layout. I believe its more simpler to use it. **The quick fix for your problem** should be that you need to set `chart.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` then constrain it to the scrollView. I included a few best practices when working with scrollViews that aren't necessarily needed. I'll edit my answer with an example you can copy paste, hang on.

Comment: @diogenes I've edited my answer. Change your `setupScrollView()` with the one i wrote. and don't forget the constant just above.

Comment: thanks for all your help. I was a looser and just went with auto layout.  once I get better I will come back and this method.  I did get it to work though.  Thanks!!!

Comment: @diogenes Auto layout is the approach I suggested above, anyway glad it worked out for you. Good luck!